# Why does password generated from "openssl passwd -1" has different length than md5sum?

Tags: encryption, hash, openssl, cryptography, md5

Say password is 000000

```
cmd> openssl passwd -1 000000
$1$noyU0rJi$iZ7EgOhutl2aJItaBcF5v.

cmd> echo -n '000000noyU0rJi' | md5sum    #cmd might be incorrect
1be6132fd5be99229741e0b88700fe95  -
```

md5sum hash should have 32 characters, but the hash from openssl is only 22 characters (iZ7EgOhutl2aJItaBcF5v). Why is that?

Edit: I got some downvote, would be helpful if you could explain why..

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least part of the difference you are seeing is that the output of the openssl tool is in the base64 format associated with the Unix crypt function [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(C) ], whereas the output of the md5 function is in hexadecimal (base16).

If you look carefully, you can see that the output of md5sum only has the digits 0-9 and the lowercase letters a-f.  The output of the openssl command has numbers and what appears to be the full alphabet, including upper and lowercase letters.

When you encode information more densely (base64), the length will naturally be shorter.